# Rails Model Inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets say I have a User model that has a field called subscriber that is a boolean and I want a subclass called Subscriber that is only Users with that field set to true. How can I do this and am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's the only difference, you might want to look at using scopes instead:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :subscribers, where(:subscriber => true)
end
```

Then you can access the subscribers as a method on the `User` class:

```
User.subscribers
# => [#<User...>, #<User...>] # List of all subscribers
```